# What is the best way to parse a web page in Ruby?

Tags: html, xml, ruby, screen-scraping

I have been looking at XML and HTML libraries on rubyforge for a simple way to pull data out of a web page.  For example if I want to parse a user page on stackoverflow how can I get the data into a usable format?

Say I want to parse my own user page for my current reputation score and badge listing.  I tried to convert the source retrieved from my user page into xml but the conversion failed due to a missing div.  I know I could do a string compare and find the text I'm looking for, but there has to be a much better way of doing this.

I want to incorporate this into a simple script that spits out my user data at the command line, and possibly expand it into a GUI application.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade but the most excellent http://modos.org/sof/?u=??? (where ??? is your id, for you it's 22423) may already do what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553/track-your-reputation for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Hpricot is over !**](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot#hpricot-is-over)

Use **[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)** now.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately stackoverflow is claiming to be XML but actually isn't.  [Hpricot](http://hpricot.com/) however can parse this tag soup into a tree of elements for you.

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Hpricot(open("http://stackoverflow.com/users/19990/armin-ronacher"))
reputation = (doc / "td.summaryinfo div.summarycount").text.gsub(/[^\d]+/, "").to_i
```

And so forth.

Answer (score 5):

try [hpricot](http://hpricot.com/), its well... awesome

I've used it several times for screen scraping.

Answer (score 0):

I always really like what Ilya Grigorik writes, and he [wrote up a nice post](http://www.igvita.com/2007/02/04/ruby-screen-scraper-in-60-seconds/) about using hpricot.

I also [read this post](http://www.rubyrailways.com/data-extraction-for-web-20-screen-scraping-in-rubyrails) a while back and it looks like it would be useful for you.

Haven't done either myself, so YMMV but these seem pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Something I ran into trying to do this before is that few web pages are well-formed XML documents.  Hpricot may be able to deal with that (I haven't used it) but when I was doing a similar project in the past (using Python and its library's built in parsing functions) it helped to have a pre-processor to clean up the HTML.  I used the python bindings for [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) as this and it made life a lot easier.  Ruby bindings are [here](http://tidy.rubyforge.org/) but I haven't tried them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be an old topic but here is a new one. Example getting reputation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

user = "619673/100kg"
html = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/%s?tab=reputation"

page = html % user
puts page

doc = Hpricot(open(page))
pars = Array.new
doc.search("div[@class='subheader user-full-tab-header']/h1/span[@class='count']").text.each do |p|
  pars << p
end

puts "reputation " + pars[0]
```