# Parse a Webpage in Ruby to retrieve URLs from it

Tags: ruby, html-parsing

I want to parse a webpage and retrieve the first few embedded urls under certain headers using ruby. For example, I have a document archive in which documents are stored as doc-type.timestamp.ext and I want to pull out all documents of the same type.

The best solution I found on was this :
[What is the best way to parse a web page in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137605/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-web-page-in-ruby)

Is there anyway I can do this without using hpricot and other such packages?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "under certain headers" and "embedded urls"?

Comment: I've given an example of the exact use-case (of the document archive). For instance, I might want to parse a page of Wikipedia to search for any occurrences of "*Obama*" which are links and retrieve the URL of the page this redirects me to. Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you not want to use an external gem? They can make your life a lot easier, take a a look at this [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) example where you can quickly output every link on the page:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

a.get('http://google.com/') do |page|
  p page.links
end
```

I've been scraping a lot lately and you can not get very far without parsing the page, I use Nokogiri with plain net/http but will switch to Mechanize in the future. Mechanize uses Nokogiri internally as well.